# Parallax effct not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, parallax

So first of all, I'm not a professional coder but I have **some** experience. I am trying to do a modern nice parallax website. So my problem is that the image in the background doesn't show in Firefox but it does in Chrome and I want it to work in both.
Here is my code:

```js
//No js yet
```

```css
#welcome {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  background-color: #D5D5D5;
  height: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1000px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#parallax {
   background-image: url("http://wp.widewallpapers.net/4k/cities/new-york/3840x2160/New-York-3840x2160-001.jpg");

    min-height: 100%; 
 margin: 0px;

    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta content="-1" http-equiv="expires"></meta>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type"></meta>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="parallax"></div>
<center><p align="center" id="welcome">Welcome To My Website!</p></center>
</body>
</html>
```

So if you copy all that and try it in chrome it works (for everyone I think), but it doesn't work in Firefox. HELP!

Comment: On a side note the `<center>` tag has been deprecated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). There are plenty of things to help with centering. Here is a good resource: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Comment: I have this question too. There's a CSS Only parallax demo site at: https://alligator.io/css/pure-css-parallax/ that works fine on every other browser except Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Simple and easy fix is to add the `height: 100%` to the `body{}`

```
  body {
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

> Additional options:

1. Change `min-height` to `height.`

   ```
   #parallax {
      background-image: url("http://wp.widewallpapers.net/4k/cities/new-  york/3840x2160/New-York-3840x2160-001.jpg");
      height: 100%; 
      margin: 0px;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
   }
   ```
2. Change `min-height: 100%` to `min-height: 580px;` (Or whatever pixel
   you want).

   ```
   #parallax {
      background-image: url("http://wp.widewallpapers.net/4k/cities/new-  york/3840x2160/New-York-3840x2160-001.jpg");
      min-height: 580px; //or whatever pixel you want... 
      margin: 0px;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
   }
   ```